# SQLite OS-abstraction layer?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, portability

Some people want to port my Android open-source software to Blackberry and PC (also using SQLite).

I separated the UI code from the domain/database code. But next problem, the domain/database code contains imports like this one:

```
import android.database.Cursor;
```

... which makes it not portable.

I guess many other developers have the same problem, so an SQLite OS-abstraction layer must exist somewhere. What would you suggest?

*Note: I use SQLite-specific features, so an ORM or a database abstraction layer will not do.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am currently developing an ORM project, especially for Android.

https://github.com/ahmetalpbalkan/orman

Which SQLite-specific features do you use?

Maybe you can create an interface, compile it with both `android.jar` and `the_jar_for_blackberry.jar` so that you can do something like in the code

```
Database db = null;    
if (environment is android){
    db = new AndroidSQLiteDatabaseImpl();
} else {
    db = new MyBlackberrySQLiteImpl();
}
```

and when both classes implement the same interface, then you won't be in the trouble. Because if you say

`import android.database.Cursor`

only in `AndroidSQLiteDatabaseImpl.java` and if you don't initialize it at all, no exceptions will be thrown.

You can look at source code of our project. At build-time, we compile it with `android.jar` however, when we ship only a single `jar` file, all desktop program users can use it for MySQL and native SQLite. Because they don't initialize `AndroidSQLiteDtabase` class and no exceptions will be thrown.

Comment: SQLite-specific feature: loading the database from a file. The rest is pretty much standard (but advanced) SQL.

Comment: My library supports that. You just give the file name then it handles the rest in Android. You can also execute native queries (however our query builder can also build advanced queries). I can assist you if you'd like to use our ORM solution.